# How can I make my Xamarin.Forms for iOS and Android application show a splash screen as soon as possible after a user has opened the application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for hints, an example or anything that could guide me with how to make a start up splash screen for Xamarin application Xamarin.Forms application.

I assume I need to make different changes to the iOS and the Android projects and have researched what I can find already.

However much of the information seems dated or no longer works.

Would appreciate any suggestions and advice on how to do this for iOS and Android.

Comment: There's some tutorials out there that show this. [This](https://medium.com/@thesultanster/xamarin-splash-screens-the-right-way-3d206120726d) is one of the more recently made ones I've found. [Here's](https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/) another one from Adam Pedley, a Microsoft MVP, but I think the iOS part is a little dated.

Comment: I tried both of these links but neither seem to help with iOS.  One is not for forms and the other is as you mention not up to date.

Comment: Do you want to open app very fast, w/o taking much time on splash screen?

Comment: @Arvindraja - I would like it to open as fast as possible and show a simple splash screen before it opens.  I am expecting I would have to implement some different code for iOS and Android in their projects and maybe there's a change I need to make to the shared code.  Hope for some good suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms is a solution that, in itself, takes a while to load. Since all cross-platform things have to wait for Xamarin, there is no cross-platform good implementation of a splash screen.

It looks like you'll have to implement it separately for iOS and Android. This will enable the splash screen to show up much faster and before the standard blue Xamarin screen.

**EDIT: Alan asked for a complete solution, so here it is:**

**iOS:** Make changes to the LaunchScreen.storyboard file in the Resources section of the .iOS project (that's the splash screen, by the way). I'd suggest opening it in Xcode instead because the storyboard editor of Xcode is frankly just better than Xamarin.

**Android:** You're going to have to have an image here. [From official Xamarin support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen)-

> The quickest way to render and display the splash screen is to create a custom theme and apply it to an Activity that exhibits the splash screen. When the Activity is rendered, it loads the theme and applies the drawable resource (referenced by the theme) to the background of the activity. This approach avoids the need for creating a layout file.
>   The splash screen is implemented as an Activity that displays the branded drawable, performs any initializations, and starts up any tasks. Once the app has bootstrapped, the splash screen Activity starts the main Activity and removes itself from the application back stack.

Here's the specific code involved for that. Below is for a drawable. Place it in the Resources/Drawable folder of the Android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is for a theme (add it to values/styles.xml, or add values/styles.xml if the document doesn't exist.).

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Add this code to your Android project as MyTheme.cs:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
    }

    // Launches the startup task
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }

    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    async void SimulateStartup ()
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of time.");
        await Task.Delay (8000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.");
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof (MainActivity)));
    }
}
```

Then, after you've done all that for Android, remove the MainLauncher attribute from MainActivity, since your launcher is now MyTheme.

This is by no means easy, but it's the only way there is right now.

Comment: Hi James, the problem is I am not sure how to do this so I added a 300 point bonus to a question which would normally mean a few people answer.  But in this case nothing yet which suggests not many others really know how to do this or nobody wants points any more :-)

Comment: @Alan2 What are you not sure about? Do you know how to add it separately? Unfortunately there's no way to do it cross-platform without writing separate code for iOS and Android

Comment: If you don't know how to do it separately I will update my answer; please let me know if you want that.

Comment: Yes I would like to have a solution that involves me making changes to the iOS and Android projects in my forms app. I would like to have as much information on how to do this and I think it would help others also. LeRoy made some suggestions but just kind of skeleton suggestions so I am hoping for something really complete with tips. I had a look around and could not find any complete examples on the internet.

Comment: @Alan2 Any better?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you do not have SimulateStartup sample code. It used to be boiler plate code a while ago:

**class SplashActivity:**

It forces an await when the app starts up incase you want to make any service calls on the splash screen

***MainActivity.cs***

```
// Launches the startup task
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
    startupWork.Start();
}

// Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
async void SimulateStartup ()
{
    Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of time.");
    await Task.Delay (8000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
    Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.");
    StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof (MainActivity)));
}
```

*Other alternative to improve splash speed:*

- use small or native components to create your splash screen
- make sure nothing is on *OnResume* and not calling any services